# Steam games mute all volume on computer

Tags: windows-8, steam

As soon as I start a steam game, the volume mutes, and so does the volume for everything on the Computer, and when i close the game, everything is still muted. If i restart my computer I can hear sound again, until i start a steam game, can someone please help?
I'm using windows 8.

Answer (score -1):

I fixed it, i did this by deleting all the folders in the steam folder, apart from steamapps, userdata, and the steam.exe and then launching steam again.